# How to select li without children in a multilevel menu with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

I have a multilevel (tree) menu built with HTML `<ul>` and `<li>`. This is a sample of that markup:

```
<ul class='dl-menu dl-menuopen'>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Fashion</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Men</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Shirts</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jackets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Chinos &amp; Trousers</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jeans</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>T-Shirts</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Underwear</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Women</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jackets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Knits</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jeans</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Dresses</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Blouses</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>T-Shirts</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Underwear</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Children</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Boys</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Girls</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Electronics</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Camera &amp; Photo</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>TV &amp; Home Cinema</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Phones</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>PC &amp; Video Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Furniture</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Living Room</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Sofas &amp; Loveseats</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Coffee &amp; Accent Tables</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Chairs &amp; Recliners</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Bookshelves</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Bedroom</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li>
            <a href='#' class='catlink'>Beds</a>
            <ul class='dl-submenu'>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Upholstered Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Divans</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Metal Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Storage Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Wooden Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Children's Beds</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Bedroom Sets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Chests &amp; Dressers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Home Office</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Dining &amp; Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Patio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Jewelry &amp; Watches</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Fine Jewelry</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Fashion Jewelry</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Watches</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Wedding Jewelry</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Engagement Rings</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Bridal Sets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Women's Wedding Bands</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Men's Wedding Bands</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to select all `<li>` nodes that has no children. I want to get the "leaves" of the tree, those elements that have no children, the final nodes.

**How can I do this with jQuery?**

Comment: As far as i can see every single one of your `<li>` has children. Do you mean to select the ones that have a second list (`<ul>`) in them or are there supposed to be empty ones?

Comment: That have no child `<li>`?  Looks like all the `<li>`s in the code at least have a child `<a>` element.

Comment: @RemcovanOs Maybe I expressed myself wrong, I want to get the "leaves" of the tree, those elements that have no children, the final nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use either of the following:

```
$(".dl-menu li:not(:has(li))")
```

or

```
$(".dl-menu li:not(:has(ul))")
```

Comment: Which is the difference between that two lines of code? Are equivalent for my case?

Comment: @alessadro in reference to your example they would be equivalent since none of the children you are looking for have a `li` or a `ul` tag. I would use the `:has(ul)` version in your example since it would come across the `ul` tag first.

Comment: Great! only a last thing, in my real case example I got some `<li.dl-back>` how can I remove the li's with that class?

Comment: You could do something like `$(".dl-menu li:not(:has(li)):not(.dl-back)")`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want all links:

```
$('li:has(a):not(:has(ul))')
```

```js
$('li:has(a):not(:has(ul))').each(function(){

console.log(
   $(this).html()
);

});
```

```css
es-console-wrapper{
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='dl-menu dl-menuopen'>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Fashion</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Men</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Shirts</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jackets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Chinos &amp; Trousers</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jeans</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>T-Shirts</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Underwear</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Women</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jackets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Knits</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Jeans</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Dresses</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Blouses</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>T-Shirts</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Underwear</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Children</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Boys</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Girls</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Electronics</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Camera &amp; Photo</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>TV &amp; Home Cinema</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Phones</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>PC &amp; Video Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Furniture</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Living Room</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Sofas &amp; Loveseats</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Coffee &amp; Accent Tables</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Chairs &amp; Recliners</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Bookshelves</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Bedroom</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li>
            <a href='#' class='catlink'>Beds</a>
            <ul class='dl-submenu'>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Upholstered Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Divans</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Metal Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Storage Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Wooden Beds</a></li>
              <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Children's Beds</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Bedroom Sets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Chests &amp; Dressers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Home Office</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Dining &amp; Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Patio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' class='catlink'>Jewelry &amp; Watches</a>
    <ul class='dl-submenu'>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Fine Jewelry</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Fashion Jewelry</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Watches</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href='#' class='catlink'>Wedding Jewelry</a>
        <ul class='dl-submenu'>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Engagement Rings</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Bridal Sets</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Women's Wedding Bands</a></li>
          <li><a href='#' class='catlink'>Men's Wedding Bands</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note here - in your example, NONE of your nodes are empty. They all have children. Some have an "a" tag, and some have a "a" AND "ul" tag. Based on your example, it looks like you want to select all "li" elements that have NO "ul" tags as children. This is called a "parent selector", and cannot be done with CSS alone (unfortunately). But it can be done in javascript, and since you want an answer in javascript, this should work:

```
$('li:not(:has(ul))').addClass('link');
```

You can further refine your query as needed.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/68tguxza/

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking only for li element without ul children then you can do this.

```js
$('li:not(:has(ul))')
```

Comment: Would love to know why the downvote since it's exactly what he needs. Just look at the accepted answer which has specificity to it but same as my solution.